# How to connect NodeJS script to ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to create something like a Amazon Price alert clone.

If I'm missing the logic and I need another technology or addition, please let me know, cause currently I'm pretty frustrated on this task.

Goal/Explanation: - I want to compare the price from Binance API which is `parseFloat(d[1])` with the price in React App, which I put in this field and If the price from API is bigger than I write in Input field, call the script.

I think I need to use Express to connect client with server. I'm pretty new in React and connecting react + Node is something new for me.

Looking forward for any help or suggestion on how I can do it.

This is react part of input field.

```
<input
type="number"
placeholder="Price"
value={price}
        onChange={onChangePrice}
      />
```

I have a script on NodeJS which is receiving data from [Binance API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs) and showing it console.

```
const getBTCData = async symbol => {
    let data = await fetch(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=1m&limit=1`).then(res => res.json());
    const btcusdtdata = data.map(d => {
        return {
            Open: parseFloat(d[1]),
        }
    });
    console.log(btcusdtdata[0]);
};
```

**Full React Code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const assets = [
  "ADABTC",
  "AIONBTC",
  "ALGOBTC",
  "ARDRBTC",
  "KAVABTC",
  "ETHBTC",
  "ETCBTC"
];

export default function App() {
  const [queries, setQueries] = useState([]);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState("");
  const [price, setPrice] = useState("");
  const [dropdown, setDropdown] = useState([]);

  const onChangeSymbol = e => {
    setSymbol(e.target.value);
  };

  const onChangePrice = e => {
    setPrice(e.target.value);
  };

  var today = new Date();
  var date =
    today.getFullYear() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + today.getDate();
  var time =
    today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  var dateTime = date + " " + time;

  const onClick = () => {
    if (symbol !== "" && price !== "") {
      setQueries(queries => {
        return [
          ...queries,
          `${symbol}` + " " + `${price}` + " " + "(" + dateTime+")"
        ];
      });
      setSymbol("");
      setPrice("");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (symbol !== "" && symbol !== assets.find(rec => rec === symbol)) {
      setDropdown(assets.filter(rec => rec.indexOf(symbol) > -1));
    } else {
      setDropdown([]);
    }
  }, [symbol]);

  return (
    <div id="DropDownArea" className="DropDownField">
      <div id="PriceAlertHistory">
        <h6>Price Alert History</h6>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {queries.map(query => (
          <li>{query}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Symbol"
        value={symbol}
        onChange={onChangeSymbol}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Price"
        value={price}
        onChange={onChangePrice}
      />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onClick}>
        Set
      </button>
      <ul>
        {dropdown.length !== 0
          ? dropdown.map(asset => {
              return (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSymbol(asset);
                    setDropdown([]);
                  }}
                >
                  {asset}
                </li>
              );
            })
          : false}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**EDIT1**

Let's say I Write in my React App > `ADABTC` and price is `500` and I click `Set` also I write that `AIONBTC` and price is `900` and `Set` button again. So I have 2 properties for now.

My NodeJS script is working and taking data from API every minute for every asset which is in the array `assets`. So it's should compare correct name of asset from API and which is in React and when the name is correct and price in API is bigger than price in React, then call the script

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are not putting the JS which you have in the Node code within the React app? If you want a user to be able to enter the values and then leave the app (close it) but still receive notifications, then you would need to have a database as part of this setup. If you only need the notifications to work while the app is open in the web browser, you could write the values to localStorage and put the node related code within the React app.

Comment: As the comment above suggests, you could have the API call function as part of the React component. If you want to keep the logic separate, then you need to expose that function through a route on the node app and the React component will need to call that.

Comment: @Jay no reason at all. Was not even thinking that I can do it. As i say I'm pretty new in react...

Comment: @NevelinaA. so basically I can call API inside React, and then just compare inside 2 numbers inside a react app? Or I'm missing logic.

Comment: @Hexycode yes you can call the API from within the React app.

Comment: @Jay but how I can compare then numbers from API and number which I write in Price input?

Comment: You have access to the price variable which gets set on input and submit and is presumably handled in the onClick function. All you need is the value of that variable and the API value which you can call in your onClick function for super timely comparison or whenever, depends on your usecase.

Comment: @Hexycode well you already have the value which you set in the price input stored in your "price" state variable, so you could have a useEffect set up with [price] in it, then every time price changes the useEffect function can run, and it can call the API, then compare the API value to the value of "price". Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jay is it possible to receive example?

Comment: @Jay cause I will need to compare different names of symbols as well and they're price.

Comment: @NevelinaA. But how I can compare the asset name and price in React with asset name and price in NodeJS?